# ruby- Couldn't find Project with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this Nested Resources Error like below:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/projects/2/project_comments

Couldn't find Project with 'id'=

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
resources :users
resources :projects do
  resources :project_users
  resources :project_comments
end
end
```

project.rb

```
has_many :project_comments
```

project_comment.rn

```
belongs_to :project
```

project_comments_co

```
class Admin::ProjectCommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_project_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]  
before_action :set_project


def your_action
    # these are for debugging
    puts params.inspect
    puts params[:option_id]
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
end

def index
    @project_comments = @project.project_comments.all
end

def new
    @project_comment = @project.project_comments.new
end

def create
    @project_comment = @project.project_comments.new(project_comment_params)

    if @project_comment.save
    else
    end
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def update
    if  @project_comment.update(project_comment_params)
    else
    end
end

def destroy
    @project_comment.destroy
end

private
def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end


def set_project_comment
    @set_project_comment = ProjectComment.find(params[:id])
end


def project_comment_params
    params.require(:project_comment).permit(:project_id, :user_id, :comment)    
end
```

end

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: In your set_project method the params[:id] should be params[:project_id] I guess

Comment: Thank you!  I solved it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are inside the `ProjectCommentsController` the `params[:id]` will give you the `id` of `ProjectComment` and not of `Project`. So in your method:

```
def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

Change the `params[:id]` to `params[:project_id]` which will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error say that Rails is not able to find any **Project** record with this id.

Is there any Project record in a database?

Please post stack trace.

Comment: I changed params[:id]  into params[:project_id] and the error was solved. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

change your set_project function with below code:

```
private 
def set_project 
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
end
```